# Checking negative input from user, working with array

Tags: c++

I am required to write a code for getting 5 positive numbers from the user.
Here is my code:

```
cout << "Write 5 positive numbers:" << endl;
int input;
int num[5];

for(int i = 0; i <= 4; ++i){
    cin >> input;
    if(input < 0){
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    }else{
        num[i] = input;
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; ++i){
    cout << "Number " << i << " = " << num[i] << endl;
}
```

The problem is that array should only store positive numbers. When I enter negative `num`, it stores it too, and then prints the garbage value. For example, inputs are: 3 -2 1 6 8
The output is:

```
Number 0 = 3
Number 1 = -1608404014
Number 2 = 1
Number 3 = 6
Number 4 = 8
```

The code should ask the user enter the input until all 5 buckets in array will be filled only with positive numbers

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you told it to. If a negative number is entered, that index of the array is skipped.

Comment: you need to use `while loop`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Garbage value is printed because if a negative number is entered, that index of the array in your code is skipped.

For your program to keep asking user for the input until the user inputs a positive value, you need a `while loop` inside your `if block` which displays `Error` message if negative value is entered.

Also you need to remove `else block` inside `for loop` from your code because that's what causing the garbage value to get printed.

Try following code

```
int main()
    {
        cout << "Write 5 positive numbers:" << endl;
        int input;
        int num[5];

        for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            cin >> input;
            if(input < 0)
           {
                cout << "Error" << endl;
                while(input < 0)
                {
                   cin>>input;
                }

            }

             num[i] = input;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
         cout << "Number " << i << " = " << num[i] << endl;
         }

         return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

because the the input value is negative you don't store it to the element `i` but only popup a message then you left this element without input and increment the loop counter and as you guess un-initialized variables have a garbage value:

the solution is to block at the negative value using an embedded wile loop for example until a valid value is inputted:

```
int input;
int num[5];

for(int i = 0; i <= 4; ++i)
{
    cin >> input;
    while(input < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        cout << "num[ " << i << "]: ";
        cin >> input;
    }
        num[i] = input;
}

for( i = 0; i <= 4; ++i){
cout << "Number " << i << " = " << num[i] << endl;
}
```